# Ruby initialize and self

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I found an interesting problem: http://rubeque.com/problems/fixing-bad-code-the-wrong-way/solutions

Generally we have a simple class (notice that we don't have `attr_accessor` here):

```
class Foo
  def itnialize(name)
    self.foo = name
  end

  def set_bar 
    self.bar = 'it will fail..'
  end
end
```

I thought that ruby will raise no method error when I call `Foo.new` but it passes without any problems. The code will fail when I try `Foo.new.bar`

How is it possible and how to access `Foo.new.foo` variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo and have miss-spelt `initialize` as `itnialize` so it won't be being called - so no error.

It looks like you're trying to create an instance variable - to do so you need, somewhere, to define it with the `@` prefix. So you might do:

```
def initialize(name)
  @foo = name
end
```

which would then mean you are able to access `@foo` inside the class.

`self.foo` can only ever refer to a *method* `foo`, so you need to define that method if you want to call it, either explicitly or by using one of the `attr` variants.

However, in this case, you could just do

```
def set_bar
  @bar = 'it will succeed!'
end
```

Comment: My bad, it seems that this puzzle http://rubeque.com/problems/fixing-bad-code-the-wrong-way/solutions makes no sense...

Comment: Just had a look at the puzzle but can't see how it's related! The puzzle does make sense though - and the title, "fixing bad code the wrong way" is *very, very apt*.

Comment: I think the thing to focus on in the puzzle is the definition of `method_missing` - you don't need to alter any code outside of this method.